# Cannot find C++ ATL Libraries (atl.lib and atl120.dll) in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, atl

I have a C++ project that uses the ATL library.  In Visual Studio 2012, I used to see the following two files:

- Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
  11.0\VC\atlmfc\lib\Atl.lib
- Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
  11.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC110.ATL\atl110.dll

The corresponding Lib and DLL files are not to be found in the Visual Studio 2013 installation.  Where can I find the corresponding files for VS2013?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2013, all the functionality inside the ATL DLL has been moved directly into the ATL headers.  So there is no need for a DLL or the associated import lib.  You just need to include the appropriate headers in your sources and all the functionality is built right into your binaries.